# React async function not returning correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, for-of-loop

I'm calling a util function in a component like this:

`const res = await makeTempTrackImports({artistName,QueryID});`

The util function calls some data from supabase, does some string methods then does an async for of loop where I call the Spotify API with the data. after this point, the data isn't consistently returning in the util function or if I try to return back to the component. Here's what the util looks like

```
export const makeTempTrackImports = async ({ artistName, QueryID }) => {
    const { data } = await 
    supabase.storage.from("audio").list(QueryID);
    const trackNames = Object.values(data).map((song) => {
        return song.name.replace(/_/g, "&").replace(".mp3", "");
    });

    let results = [];
    for await (const songName of trackNames) {
        const res = await getTrackIds({songName, artistName});
        if (res === 0 || res === undefined) return;
        results.push(res.tracks.items);
    }
    return results; <-- stops working by here
};
```

the result will show up in the console inconsistently but won't actually be returned in the program. thank you in advance

Comment: is `trackNames` really an *async iterable*? (hint: it wouldn't be in the code you presented) Also, can you format your code correctly -

Comment: `if (res === 0 || res === undefined) return;` will exit the function, returning `undefined` ... that won't "continue" the for loop

Comment: @JaromandaX [for await...of works on both sync and async iterables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of)

Comment: @MichaelBrenndoerfer - yes it does - so, I guess since it's a the newest `for` toy, it should be used even when it's completely inappropriate

Comment: Well, it's necessary in order to be able to call an async function as part of the loop. Otherwise, genuine question, how would you loop over a collection and make async calls? (`Promise.all` only if I need to call and wait for them all)

Comment: @MichaelBrenndoerfer No, it's **not** necessary to make async function calls or await them in the loop body! You can (and should) just `await` promises in a normal `for … of` loop

Answer (score 0):

You are returning too early. the return will return from the function scope, not returning the empty `[]` results array. Slight change of your if condition should do the trick.

```js
for await (const songName of trackNames) {
    const res = await getTrackIds({
        songName,
        artistName
    });
    if (res) results.push(res.tracks.items);
    // or if (res === 0 || res === undefined) return results;
    
}
return results;
```

Answer (score 0):

working solution: change the for of loop to

```
const results = await Promise.all(
  trackNames.map(
    (songName) => getTrackIds({songName, artistName})
  )
);
```